# How to do a randomizer to take an option out of an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am trying to do a randomly generated madlib with an array for an assignment. I need to make  6 arrays(which I have already made) with different numbers. Arrays place, name, verb, animal, and phrase has 5 options and object has 6 and country has 9. I need to make a randomizer to pick out an option from each array to put into a madlib.

Comment: You could use the [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library

Comment: You mean select an item in an array and not remove the item from the array, yes? Get the size of the array and use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to get a number in the range \[0,size of array). If you don't want repeats, [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the array once and go through it one by one until you hit the end.